# How to make a QGIS 3 Layer refresh after a joined data source is updated

Tags: layers, symbology, qgis-3

I have a layer of ZCTA features that is sourced from a SpatiaLite table that is joined to an Excel spreadsheet and rendered with categorized symbology.  That all works fine. The join configuration is:

[image]

I have found that after I edit the spreadsheet (using the column that the categorized renderer uses), I can turn the layer off, and then turn it on again.  And the layer will refresh and change color. **But only once.**  Subsequent updates to the spreadsheet do not trigger any changes in the QGIS Layer.

I am setting up this project for a non-GIS user, so I'm hoping to avoid any PyQGIS as presented in these answers: [Make a Qgis layer update from a changed data source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159950/make-a-qgis-layer-update-from-a-changed-data-source)

Does this capability exist in QGIS 3? Something like an "Update All Data Sources" for a selected layer?