# QGIS parsing layer source

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, ogr

I periodically need to refresh my QGIS map based on changed underlying data sources (currently locally-saved KML, GPKG, but trying to be general) using PyQGIS. Following [Make a Qgis layer update from a changed data source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159950/make-a-qgis-layer-update-from-a-changed-data-source), for a *specific* layer I can use:

```
layer.dataProvider().forceReload()
layer.triggerRepaint()
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

However, I need to find *all* current layers depending on a specific updated source, and also *keep track of the layers* found vs the layers (=database tables, KML folders) in the source. The latter is to alert the user if there are map layers to deprecate that are no longer in the datasource, or new ones in the datasource to potentially add and style. For this I need to parse `layer.source()` to extract filename and (source as opposed to map) layer name.

What's a robust, non-provider specific, and reasonably future-proof way of doing this? At the moment, all the relevant sources are loaded via `ogr`, and by inspection the relevant sourcestring has the URI-like format `full_filename|layername=table_or_folder_name_in_source` and sometimes also  `...|geometrytype=Point_or_LineString_or_Whatever`. Therefore I use a simple `if filename in layer.source()` to find layers that need updating, and `layer.source().split('|layername=')[1].split('|')[0]` to pick out the layer name in the source file. But this could be confused by layers with different providers (e.g. a WMS layer whose URI happens to have a confounding substring) and for all I know ogr could change its datasource string format at any time.

More specifically, is there either a method/function to parse a `layer.source()` string into meaningful components, or -- failing that -- a documented canonical format for the string? I've noticed some providers use `&` as a delimiter but others `|`.

Answer (score 3):

because data source parsing depends of provider you have to:

```
QgsProviderRegistry.instance().decodeUri( layer.providerType(), layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri() )
```

so in case of a file based provider you have

```
decoded = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().decodeUri( layer.providerType(), layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri() )
decoded['path']
```