# Create screenshot of each polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins

I have a grid covering some area and roads shapefile on the map. Now I want to make a screenshot of each grid square and save it as a picture. How I can do that using qgis? I have searched for plugins but with no success. Also I have tried to use print composer but I can't do the right thing for each square.

Comment: This can be done with the print Composer. What goes wrong when you try?

Comment: @BERA I want to do that automatically for whole grid. There is a lot of squares. If I use print composer I should go square by square manually.

Comment: No you can automate it using print Composer. See "Atlas generation": https://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html#atlas-generation

Comment: @BERA Great! Write this comment as answer on this question and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: if you need worldfile with your screenshot you should use a script as it show on this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/210113/53945

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Atlas Generation feature.

Here is a good tutorial:  http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/automating_map_creation.html

Here are the docs:  https://qgis-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/user_manual/print_composer/atlas_generation.html