# PostGIS layer QGIS 2.18.12 autorefresh at 10 seconds

Tags: qgis, python

I am using a database view as a source to draw a line over a map in QGIS 2.18.12.
This view contains just one registration and it changes from time to time.
I would like to draw the line automatically when the view changes.
Is it possible to do this from a Python script?
For the moment my solution is to reload the whole project, but it is not as fine as I expected because I want to refresh just the line not all layers.

The code I use now is:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer

timer = QTimer()

timer.setInterval(10000)
QObject.connect(timer, 
SIGNAL("timeout()"),qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers)
timer.start()
```

Comment: Does this answer help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/136405/25417 You could add a check for each layer in the loop, and only refresh if it matches the layer you want to update.

Comment: Hmm. It is not OK. I would like to reload only the PostGIS layer  (the line), but thank you.

Comment: If you know the name of the layer, then maybe you could adapt that answer? e.g. `for layer in qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layers():` then inspect `layer` to see if it matches your criteria, then `layer.triggerRepaint()`?

Comment: Ok! I know my layer name and I have already changed qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers with layerName.triggerRepaint. I am having an  error ---- NameError: name 'layerName' is not defined. This is my problem

Comment: It looks like your answer is OK for my need, but with few adjustments. I am new in Python and QGIS technology. Thank you! Have a nice week!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would be better:

```
# import only the things you need
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer

layer_name = 'layer' # Define the name of your layer here (change 'layer' to your layer name) 

def refresh():
    """refresh the layer with name 'layer_name'"""
    # get your layer by name
    layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    # refresh your layer
    layer.triggerRepaint()

timer = QTimer()
timer.setInterval(10000) # 10 seconds
timer.timeout.connect(refresh) # Better to use the new signal/slot syntax
timer.start()
```

You can run this code in a Qgis2.X python console

Closing QGIS will make all that stops, you may want to add the possibility to stop this script while QGIS is running, but it's another topic.