# Making QGIS layer update from changed .geojson data source

Tags: qgis, geojson, layers, data-source

I have the same problem as [Making QGIS layer update from changed data source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159950).

However, I cannot get the solution proposed by Matthias Kuhn in a [comment on an answer to that question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159950/make-a-qgis-layer-update-from-a-changed-data-source#comment585959_160151) to work.

I am using QGIS 3.4, I have loaded a .geojson file as a vector layer and am trying to refresh it without removing and re-adding. The map refreshes when I move it but the attribute table is not re-loaded.
I may not have understood how to use the reload function so here are my steps, I am using the Python Console.

```
       mc = iface.mapCanvas()
       layer = mc.currentLayer()
       layer.name()
       'radarOutGJTemp'  #--- Correct

       # Tried the following with errors attached
       layer.dataProvider().reload()
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorDataProvider' object has no attribute 'reload'  

       layer.dataProvider.reload('radarOutGJTemp')
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'reload'  

       layer.dataProvider.reload(radarOutGJTemp)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'reload'
```

I can see the function reload appear in a window as I type. I did try to import reload just in case, that failed but again I could see it appear in the window as I typed.

```
import reload
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reload'
```

Comment: The method `reload()` belongs to the `QgsRasterDataProvider` class. You are working with a `QgsVectorDataProvider` object. This class has the method `forceReload()`. Did you try that?

Comment: Your answer makes sense, I had not realised. I think I may be missing something basic, this is my first attempt at Python in Qgis although I am programming in Python.

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'forceReload' for all variations of the line. I can select the function so it does exist.    I had missed the first setup step from my question so will add it to the code above.

Comment: That suggests that you didn't include the parentheses after `dataProvider()` needed to actually call the method, `layer.dataProvider().forceReload()` should work. However, I see that `forceReload()` is deprecated and will be removed in Qgis 4. So you could use the `reloadData()` method inherited by all subclasses of `QgsDataProvider`. E.g. `layer.dataProvider().reloadData()`. I haven't tested mind you- I'm just going off the docs.

Comment: That was it, I am sorry, parenthesis were missing. I will do a bit more testing and post an update.

Answer (score 3):

With help from @BenW, the following lines refresh my map when I run them in the QGIS Python console using QGIS v3.4.

```
  mc = iface.mapCanvas()
  layer = mc.currentLayer()
  layer.dataProvider().reloadData()
  layer.triggerRepaint()
```

The final step is explained in the following post.
[Does mapCanvas().refresh() not work in QGIS 2.6?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136401/does-mapcanvas-refresh-not-work-in-qgis-2-6)